# How do I navigate an XML file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Until now I've used this:

```
f = File.open("./Public/files/file.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
puts doc.at('conversionRateDetail').text
f.close
```

And my XML sample is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply>
            <replyStatus>
                <status>
                    <advisoryTypeInfo>123</advisoryTypeInfo>
                </status>
            </replyStatus>
            <conversionRate>
                <conversionRateDetail>
                    <currency>USD</currency>
                </conversionRateDetail>
            </conversionRate>
        </Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, `doc.at('conversionRateDetail')` always returns 'nil'.

Comment: works for me. what version ruby and nokogiri are you using?

Comment: Nokogiri 1.4.6 and JRuby 1.5.6

Comment: This may or may not help you with this problem, but since you're using JRuby, you might want to consider upgrading to Nokogiri 1.5.0, which uses a [pure Java backend](http://nokogiri.org/CHANGELOG_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your code for loading the file isn't done the Ruby way:

```
File.open("./Public/files/file.xml") do |f|
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
  puts doc.at('conversionRateDetail').text
end
```

but that doesn't address why you are not able to access `conversionRateDetail`. Using `nokogiri -v` ...

```
# Nokogiri (1.5.0)
    --- 
    warnings: []

    nokogiri: 1.5.0
    ruby: 
      version: 1.9.2
      platform: x86_64-darwin10.6.0
      description: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
      engine: ruby
    libxml: 
      binding: extension
      compiled: 2.7.3
      loaded: 2.7.3
```

I am able to access `conversionRateDetail`:

```
xml = <<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply>
            <replyStatus>
                <status>
                    <advisoryTypeInfo>123</advisoryTypeInfo>
                </status>
            </replyStatus>
            <conversionRate>
                <conversionRateDetail>
                    <currency>USD</currency>
                </conversionRateDetail>
            </conversionRate>
        </Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOT

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.at('conversionRateDetail').text # => "\n                    USD\n                "
```

I'd recommend you use this instead though:

```
doc.at('conversionRateDetail currency').text # => "USD"
```

Comment: I did upgrade to nokogiri 1.5.0 and I still get NIL from doc.at('conversionRateDetail currency')

Comment: OK... so the problem appears to be the namespace in "Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply" (which i did not paste in my example). That makes nokogiri crash for some reason...

Comment: Please capture the output of `nokogiri -v` and append it to the end of your original question by editing it.